# Can I describe class methods' arguments in a reusable way?

Tags: typescript

Let's assume the following piece of code.

```ts
class MyClass {
  method1(arg1: string, arg2: number, arg3: number) {}
    
  method2(arg1: string, arg2: number, arg3: number) {}
}
```

I'd like to take the part that says `arg1: string, arg2: number, arg3: number` and express it in a way that I could reuse.
Hopefully the below example would make sense, even if it obviously doesn't work

```js
interface MyClassMethodArgs {
  arg1: string;
  arg2: number; 
  arg3: number;
}

interface MyClass {
  // How can I express "arg1: string, arg2: number, arg3: number" as MyClassMethodArgs?
  method1(arg1: string, arg2: number, arg3: number): void;
  method2(arg1: string, arg2: number, arg3: number): void;
}

class MyClassImpl implements MyClass {
  // How can I inherit the types of MyClass without repeating them?
  method1(arg1, arg2, arg3) {}
    
  method2(arg1, arg2, arg3) {}
}
```

Comment: Reusing is not a goal on itself. And reusing is not accomplished this way. Reusing works at the component level, if it makes sense.

Comment: @axiac the goal is really to maintain fewer things and to express that the methods are there to handle the same input in different ways. Which you could argue is also the job of having a class in the first place. But that's too meta for this question here.

Comment: Are there multiple implementations of `interface MyClass`?

Comment: Let's assume in one case yes, in another case no. What were you going to point out in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
type ThreeNumberFunction = (a: number, b: number, c: number) => void

class MyClass {
  method1: ThreeNumberFunction = (a, b, c) => {
    // ...
  };
  method2: ThreeNumberFunction = (a, b, c) => {
    // ...
  };
}
```

Unfortunately, this has the downside of creating new functions for each instance of the class, instead of looking up the methods on the class, so it may degrade performance and use more memory. Personally, unless the method signatures were very complicated, or I specifically needed the functions to be bound to the instance so I could pass around `obj.method1` without having to call `obj.method1.bind(obj)`, then I would just not worry about the small amount of duplication.

Also, note that you can't do the same thing using an interface, because parameter types are not inferred from the interface's method signatures:

```
interface MyInterface {
  method1: ThreeNumberFunction;
  method2: ThreeNumberFunction;
}

// parameters implicitly have type 'any'
class MyClass2 implements MyInterface {
  method1(a, b, c) {
    // ...
  }
  method2(a, b, c) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgJwhAcgVwLYCMIIGJoB2AxsAJYD2hUAvFABQCGAXFIZjggDRRavvZcPYvw64AlLQB8UAG4UyAEwCwAKDXEANowDOOqAFkQAYW16oAbzVQoGCMDgVFARlbwkqMfiKlK1Okw8WMKSNDJWqjY2APTRUAB0idZQAL4A3Ml2Dk4ATG6IyOiC3iTkVLQMjEEh0pbJMXGJ8cnpailqamSEwLgAZozE0EYAkt19A9ARNlmOLvkeRZwEpX4Zkbb2s3mwBZ7Fy75Ua+3qqrFQYIwIjFm4+mQYYJpkxGTAmiBQcIyy0KCQUAA5IxCCBARozPojKZdDoclAHk8IHZulCQKMegh+oM6usZk5nIFeDUplFzk0WplNrkicEoMRJKSGgkkusTicgA)

Comment: Thank you, this is quite helpful. I assumed that this was the case but was hoping that there was a way to describe it with no downsides. Hopefully the language will mature more in the future in that direction.